# Delete Error: Unknown Column in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

Working on a database for a school project.  I have used the following basic line of PHP code in other parts of my database with success (modified for other tables and values of course):

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM Rank WHERE RankAbb=" . $_REQUEST["RankAbb"];
```

Table name is Rank
Column name is RankAbb
Value in RankAbb is a VARCHAR(10)

This line of code has worked so far on CHAR and INT values.

I have a hyperlinked 'DELETE' button next to each tuple where you should be able to click the link, it references this code, and deletes it from the table.

RankAbb PayGrade      FullRank
1stLt O-2   First Lieutenant    DELETE  EDIT

If I click on the DELETE link I get the following error:

> Error: DELETE FROM Rank WHERE RankAbb=1stLt
>   Unknown column '1stLt' in 'where clause'

I've reached my capacity to effectively troubleshoot and decompose the problem.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap the value in quotes. This fixes your initial problem. But to avoid problems in the future see Jay Blanchard's comment.

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM Rank WHERE RankAbb='" . $_REQUEST["RankAbb"] . "'";
```

Comment: Better yet would be to use prepared queries and bound variables.  [Prevent SQL Injection!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)